# Do not auto refresh the embedded widget

Tags: portal, servicenow

Guys I am showing `approved records` in a list view in the portal. Each record contains edit `button` and am calling another widget in edit button using .

Here I am auto refreshing the `approved records` widget for every 10 seconds but the embedded `<sp-widget></sp-widget>` also getting refreshed.I don't want to refresh the ''.I just want to auto refresh the `approved records` list widget only. How can I achieve this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the widget will refresh **embedded** widgets also. I would suggest only to refresh list of records by manually calling for certain interval.

Make use of `setInterval(function, milliseconds)`